# undefined function error from a module inside class in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `module Helper` which is present `in app/models/concerns/helper.rb`

```
module Helper
  def func
    return ['A', 'B', 'C']
  end
end
```

I have a class `NewService` which is present in `app/services/pqr/new_service.rb`

```
module PQR
  class NewService < ApplicationService
    include Helper
    @@results = func

    def self.another_func
      if @@results.blank?
        @@results = func
      end
    end
  end
end
```

On calling the function: `PQR::NewService.another_func` 
I am getting the error: `(undefined local variable or method func for PQR::NewService:Class)`

```
Ruby version - 2.5.3
Rails version - 5.2.3
```

Comment: Since you are using Rails you might want to take a look into [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) – it allows you to define mixins containing instance methods and class methods more easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `func` from inside class scope; why would you expect instance-scoped methods to be accessible from there? This is an MCVE for your code

```rb
class Foo
  def func; end # instance method
  func          # class scope
end
```

To make `func` accessible, one should make it available on class level. That means, you should include your concern into `singleton_class` of `PQR`.

Contrived example:

```rb
module Foo
  def func; puts "YO"; end
end

class Bar
  class << self
    include Foo
  end

  func
end
```

Comment: Can you please share a link so that I can read in detail what you are saying?
I am not getting it completely.

Comment: Share a link to what exactly? This is [`Object#singleton_class`](https://ruby-doc.org/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class). The difference between scopes is described in books. I am not sure what link do you want me to share.

Comment: Share a link to this: you should include your concern into singleton_class of PQR. I actually don't know how to do that.

Comment: I have updated an answer with one of the possible ways of doing that. Also, `Bar.singleton_class.include` would work etc. This is core ruby functionality, I doubt there is a direct link to _that_. It’s usually described in last chapters of books.

Comment: I did not propose `extend` on purpose: it actually hides the issue, not solves it. I mean, by calling `extend` one _actually_ includes the module into the singleton class. This might sound cumbersome, but I’d strongly suggest to understand this concept instead of blindly trying `extend` even despite it works as expected.

Comment: Why does `extend` hide the issue? Isn't `class << self ; include Foo ; end` just a more cumbersome way to say `extend Foo`?

Comment: @Stefan OK, I exaggerated it and the wording was not good enough; the thing I wanted to share is **where methods are actually declared**. That’s the main key to understanding what’s happening and why it’s not working.

Answer (score 3):

You're including the Helper, not extending it.

e.g you're calling func in the class definition but you added it as an instance method

Basically, do

```
extend Helper
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. Changed the include Helper to extend Helper.

Comment: Are you sure? I've actually run your code and it works perfectly fine for me. Same Ruby version and everything.

Comment: My bad. I changed the func to self.func also. Yeah, it is working fine.

Comment: Hmm, that's really odd. I didn't use self.func because the self should be implicit. But I guess whatever, it's the same thing.

Comment: @TedTran2019 _"I changed the func to self.func"_ probably means `def self.func`, i.e. the definition, not the call.